# How long does it take for my skill group to expire?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I often play CS:GO after long hiatus's due to work and school, and most of the time, when I come back, my ranking has become "unranked", and displays the message "You need to win 1 more game to show your ranking".

My question is how long it takes for these skill groups to expire? I used to be a DMG, then stopped playing for 6 months, then came back, found I was unranked, won 1 match, and became double AKs.  Then I stopped playing for another 4 months, came back, was unranked, won 1 match, and became GN3.      I have recently come back after 3.5 months in hiatus, and have found out I am unranked.  I really do not like trying to win 1 match just to see my rank go lower and lower, so I ask how long does it take for these skill groups to expire, so I will not have to worry about losing my rank.

Comment: I believe it's about 2 weeks of "Inactivity". This means 2 weeks of not playing competitive games.

Comment: I need concrete proof, not personal anecdotes, because I really want to be sure it's exactly 2 weeks, not 1 week and 3 days or something

Comment: Just a thought, it may not be a fixed amount of time but some formula. This may be why different accounts document different time frames. (I.E. http://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/2g0n8w/skill_group_has_expired_due_to_inactivity/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The csgo wiki says that:

> If a player does not participate in competitive matchmaking for 4 weeks, the player's skill group will be hidden, and will require the player to win or draw an additional competitive match to be re-placed in a skill group.

Source:http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Competitive

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a definitive proven answer, but from my experience, my friends and 
by reading various other posts around the web ( stemcommunity,... ), **I'm almost 100% sure it's a Month**

Comment: Your answer has no sources, [the accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/283609/198327) states the same.